# It’s another Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My suffix is in a book,
>   But my prefix is up above,
>   My infix is a fruit,
>   But my whole is like X and 2000.
>
> My end is a sibling,
>   My start, where Gordy Freeman went,
>   In my middle you’ll find information,
>   Like father like son? More like no correlation!

Answer (score 3):

The second half looks like

> MITOSIS

My end is a sibling,

> Possibly a SIS.

My start, where Gordy Freeman went,

> From Half-Life, he went to MIT.

In my middle you’ll find information,

> 0, or O might be one state of binary information.

Like father like son? More like no correlation,

> This could be some genetics reference, since cells in mitosis divide themselves identically.

Comment: Close, but not yet correct

Answer (score 0):

Just a far fetched guess (but it might give other people an idea) for riddle 1
is it

> Highjacking (I know it's hijacking, but some dictionaries also allowed it written like this)

Prefix is up above

> high

My infix is a fruit

> Jack from a [jackfruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackfruit)

My suffix is in a book

> not to sure maybe a reference to KING, Stephen King?

X2000

> is a train type, hijacking a train?

Comment: Good idea, but it’s all 1 riddle

Comment: @RohitJose ohh good that you say so, thought it where 2 :p.